# Verify that dynamic links are displayed on the page using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a table with names in the database - [id] [name]
I also have a webpage where i have a generic page with all the names and each name is a link.

At the moment I'm checking that all names that are in the database are displayed on the page. I would like to check that all the names are actual links. I started with trying to get all the links from the page with this :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "a")]
public IList<IWebElement> allLinks { get; set; }
```

and putting them in a list like this

```
    foreach (IWebElement element in allLinks)
       {
           try
           {
               myLinkList.Add(element.GetAttribute("href"));
           } catch (Exception e)
           {
               throw;
           }
       }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting only nulls from `.GetAttribute("href")`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm probably doing everything right, but AngularJS :/ Just noticed that I get null for href as there is no href attribute. When inspected the link looks like this :

`<a ng-click="HomePage.registerDetail($event, row.registerId)" class="ng-binding">myDynamicLink</a>`

The link itself, when clicked, is :

```
http://myurl.com/#/entityOverview/[id]
```

So the question now, how can I get Selenium to click that link or get the href for that link?

Comment: The name is part of the href?

Comment: Nope, name is displayed, id is part of the href.

Comment: You could do a foreach for your id's that contains a method to check if the element exists for a css selector based on the id like a[href*="id_variable"]

Comment: I edited the question. It seems there is no href. The link is built by AngularJS on the fly I guess. No idea how ng-click works. The id part is in the final link but is not in the href attribute of the link element.

Answer (score 0):

This is case, there is no hRef attribute as it uses click event to trigger actions just like buttons (to use "a" instead of "button" is simply to get look and feel of link type). you can check ng-click attribute instead of href

Comment: Can I do that with Selenium somehow?

Comment: .GetAttribute("ng-click")